# Why isn't my function printing out the first node in the doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm writing a program to simulate a CPU scheduler. As such, I'm implementing a doubly linked list to use as a ready queue. Whenever a new process is added, a process control block (PCB) is created and added to the ready queue. Each PCB has a unique PID given to it. As such, I increment the PID by 1 whenever a new PCB is added.

```
pid += 1;
currentDevices[0].enqueuePCB(pid);
 //currentDevices[0] represents the ready queue. There are other queues as well
```

This is my enqueuePCB function:

```
void device::enqueuePCB(int num)
{
    pcb* newPCB = new pcb();
    newPCB -> pid = num;
    newPCB -> next = NULL;
    newPCB -> prev = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tail = newPCB;
        queueLength += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        pcb* temp = tail;
        newPCB -> next = tail;
        temp -> prev = newPCB;
        tail = newPCB;
        queueLength += 1;
    }
}
```

and my print function

```
void device::snapReadyQueue()
{
    pcb* temp = head;
    cout << "PID: ";
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp -> pid << " ";
        temp = temp -> prev;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

When I tested out my program, adding just one PCB and printing results in a a blank "PiD: ". However, once I started adding more PCB's and printing, I actually can retrieve the PIDs of the other PCBs. For example, adding 2 more PCB after the first and printing will get me

PID: 2 3

The 1 is missing and I don't understand why. I looked through my if else statement for enqueue and it seems to make sense. I've also tried using a singly linked list, but it doesn't work.

**Update**
After a bit of testing, I realized it might have to do with an if-else statement I use prior to initializing the queue.

```
 if (processCount == 0)
    {
        cout << "Currently no processes in the ready queue.\nAvailable commands: A: ";
        cin >> call;
        if (call == "A")
        {
            pid = 1;
            currentDevices[0].enqueuePCB(pid);
            processCount += 1;
            run();
        } 
    }
else
    {
        cout << "Please enter call: ";
        cin >> call;
        if (call == "A")
        {
            pid += 1;
            currentDevices[0].enqueuePCB(pid);
            processCount += 1;
            run();
        }
```

I've tried printing just the head when I enqueued the first time, and my program crashes. Yet when I add the second PCB in, the head is pointing to PID 2.

Comment: Should not `head` be the *first* node in your list? Then how can it have a *previous* node? I'm also not so sure about how you link your nodes into an non-empty list, it looks weird (I'll have to draw it on paper to be sure, always a good thing to do with lists). Also, you *do* initialize the `head` and `tail` pointers to `nullptr` (or `0` or `NULL`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I noticed this, but he also iterates backwards using `prev` so it should cancel itself out perhaps.

Comment: Why build your own list when you can use `std::list`?

Comment: Your error is inconsistent with the code visible above.  You should be seeing that first node printed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I indeed set head and tail to NULL. I iterated using prev because when I was drawing it out, I went from left to right. Again, it'll show PID 2+, when I add more, but it just won't show PID 1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you mean? I've tested it multiple times, and no matter what I tried, the first node doesn't show up. Any other node is fine except that first one.

Comment: If you add just a single node, and then try to print it, do you get output?

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't. Output would be "PID: ". Once I add the second PCB and print, it shows "PID: 2" and so on

Comment: Someone is going to have to debug this, either you or some SO user.  I don't see anything obvious right now.  I have upvoted your question.  As a side note, your `prev` and `next` pointers are backwards, not broken per se.

Comment: You are going to have to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. As @TimBiegeleisen says the problem you're having is not consistent with the code you show. The only "problem" with the code you show is that `tail` will point to the *first* note in the list, and `head` will point to the *last*. That's okay since your iteration (as you show it) uses the `prev` pointer to go *backwards* in the list. It should however iterate over all elements in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the head and tail fields to NULL in your constructor? This could cause issues inside of device::enqueuePCB if they are not.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the code for adding an element to the list is wrong, You say:

```
    pcb* temp = tail;
    newPCB -> next = tail;
    temp -> prev = newPCB;
    tail = newPCB;
    queueLength += 1;
```

Assuming that tail is a pointer to the last element of the list we can track what is going on here. Let's forget about `temp` right now, You tell the `newPCB` that its next element is the tail (the current last element). Next you tell the `tail` that its predecessor is the `newPCB` and after that you make the `newPCB` the tail. Therfore, the tail is the `newPCB`, its previous element is `NULL` but it's next element is what was the `tail` before. I think what you mean is this:

```
    tail -> next = newPCB;
    newPCB -> prev = tail;
    tail = newPCB;
```